# Python Pandas get one text value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of information.  One column is a rank.  I just want to find the row with a rank of 2 and get the another column item (called 'Name'.)  I can find the row and get the name but its not a pure text item that I can add to other text.  Its an object.

How do I just get the name as text?

Code:

```
print "The name of the 2nd best is: " + groupDF.loc[(DF['Rank']==2),'Name']
```

This gives me the id of the row and the `Name`.  I just want the `Name`

This is what I get:

```
4    The name of the 2nd best is: Hawthorne

    Name: CleanName, dtype: object
```

I just can't figure out what to search on to get the answer.  I get lots of other stuff but not this answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try:  `groupDF.iloc[(DF['Rank']==2)]]['Name']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a little bit more detail:

I understand you have a data frame of the kind:

```
names = ["Almond","Hawthorn","Peach"]
groupDF = pd.DataFrame({'Rank':[1,2,3],'Name':names})
```

`groupDF.loc[(groupDF['Rank']==2),'Name']` gives you a Series object. If the rank is unique then either of the following two possibilities works

```
groupDF.loc[(groupDF['Rank']==2),'Name'].item()
```

or

```
groupDF.loc[(groupDF['Rank']==2),'Name'].iloc[0]
```

result:

```
'Hawthorn'
```

If the rank is not unique, the second one still works and gives you the first hit, that is, the first element of the Series object created by the command.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `item()` method of the resulting `Series` object.